# java.net.UnknownHostException error in InetAddress

Tags: java, android, ip-address

I was initializing an InetAddress object(`InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("94.29.38.209");`) and got an `UnknownHostException`.

Any other IP gives this error too. If I use `InetAddress address = new InetAddress("94.29.38.209");`, Android Studio says it's private, so I can't use it.

Note that I have added Internet permission in Manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the `getByName()` method that time you need to pass a domain name instead of ip address.

Note that if you are using the `InetAddress` class, it may throws `UnknownHostException`, so you need to handle it by using the try & catch exception handling.

Comment: "When you are using the getByName() method that time you need to pass a domain name instead of ip address." i tried google.com, nothing changed

Comment: Can you handled the UnknownHostException using try catch block?